# Can't call function from body onload (uncaught reference error: start is not defined) javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a body onload calling a function in javascript. I Have tried many things, but the console just prints to the error log: uncaught reference error: start is not defined. I think it might be a malfunction, please notify me if it works for you. My code is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Monster Invasion</title>
    <script type="javascript">
      var hur;
      var monsters = 10;
      var objective = false;
      var health = 100;
      var damage = 30;
      var sheild = false;
      var ea = 1;
      function start() {
        setTimeout(hurt,4000)
      }
      function hurt() {
        var newhelth = health - damage;
        
        health = newhelth;
        document.getElementById("healtw").innerHTML = health;
        start();
      }
      
      function kill() {
        if(monsters > 0) {
        monsters--;
        document.getElementById("monster1").src="dead.jpg"
        
        setTimeout(next,2000)
        }else {
          objective = true;
          document.location="endoflevel.html";
        }
      
      }
      function next() {
        document.getElementById("monster1").src="monster.jpg"
        
      }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="start()">
    <p id="healtw"></p>
    <embed src="guide_first_level.mp3" type="audio/mp3" hidden="true" autostart="true">
    <a id="st" onclick="kill()"><img id="monster1" src="monster.jpg"></a>
    <p id="ada"></p>
    <a href="sheild.html">Activate sheild</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

your script type is wrong.

try like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

However, you don't need to mention script type. just use a plain script tag.

like this

```
<script>
</script>
```

One more thing to add that before the end of the script tag, you gave an extra `}`.

just remove it

```
function next() {
   document.getElementById("monster1").src="monster.jpg"
}
} // <-- just remove this bracket
</script>
```

Comment: When I saw the questions I rolled up my sleeves knowing that someone will give a .ready() answer when a simple end-of-document script tag will do. your answer is exactly what I'd write. you're good man @Anik.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code.

1. **javascript** is not a valid type for the script in the browser. Browsers know `text/javascript`, but not just **javascript**, that is why your code is not being executed. Change the type attribute or remove it at all (for `text/javascript` is the default value).
2. You have an extra bracket } at the end of the code. Remove it and your code will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well for some of you,   who are using external js file, please just  check to see whether you linked your file or not :)... because I  had the same error but as I looked through my code ..I hadn't  linked the file then!

**just in case you came here  looking for an answer too!**

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 errors:

- Correct the `type` of your script tag
- There is an extra `}` at the end of your code
- Instead of using `onload()` for `body` tag, you should better use `window.onload` as follows in order to make sure your `start()` function is run once document is ready:

```html
    ...
    <head>   
    <title>Monster Invasion</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function(){

                // Put all your code here
                // And at the end run start() function
                start();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
```