# onLoad on Chrome gives Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing some javascript for the first time and try to call it to the body on load. It seems to work without any problems in Incognito modus in Chrome, but in normal mode it gives a ReferenceError.

It works perfectly in Safari (normal and incognito), Internet Explorer (normal and incognito) and Chrome (only incognito). In Chrome Normal modus, it gives the error.

```
// javascript.js
function onLoad()
{
    var language_get = Cookies.get('language');

    if (language_get == null) {

        setLang();

        } else {

        var language_code = Cookies.get('language');

        document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = language[language_code];
    }

    var card_load = Cookies.get('card');

    document.getElementById("card_out").innerHTML = card_load;
}

// index.html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad();">
```

The error Console in Chrome gives:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: onLoad bs00-01.html:14 is not defined
    at onload (bs00-01.html:14)
```

Comment: Move the script part to the line right before closing the body tag.

Comment: See this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31396502/cant-call-function-from-body-onload-uncaught-reference-error-start-is-not-def

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems, there was an old version of my javascript file stored in the cache of Chrome. I did a hard refresh and now everything works fine!

I always have to navigate directly to my javascript (or css) file in Chrome and do a hard refresh. It's really annoying!

Comment: Chrome: you can do `Ctrl + Maj + R` to clear the cache, it's faster

Answer (score 1):

First fix:

Javascript is case sensitive. Meaning that `<body onload="OnLoad();">` will look for a method `OnLoad()`, rather than `onLoad()`.

The Uncaught Reference Error probably refers to *the reference to `OnLoad`* that can not be found.

Second fix:

Below i put exactly your code and the function call works (but says `Cookies` is not defined because it's not provided in the OP).

This leads me to believe that you're not correctly linking the javascript file.

```js
function onLoad()
{
    var language_get = Cookies.get('language');

    if (language_get == null) {

        setLang();

        } else {

        var language_code = Cookies.get('language');

        document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = language[language_code];
    }

    var card_load = Cookies.get('card');

    document.getElementById("card_out").innerHTML = card_load;
}
```

```html
<body onload="onLoad();">
```

Comment: Sorry; my mistake. It's written as "onLoad();" in the code.

Comment: In that case could you provide us with the entire error you're receiving? Uncaught reference to what?

Comment: Edited in the first post.

Comment: @FreddyRibs can you check in the network tab in chrome developer tools whether javascript.js is being loaded?

Comment: It seems it is called correctly; but if I open it in the network tab, it looks like an old version of my code?!

Comment: Are you using a service worker by any chance? Try disabling that for a moment. Or otherwise enable versioning of your assets, which might prevent this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

UnknownReference error is returned when there is a reference to an unknown object like using a method in an object that does not exist.

Looking at the code, it looks like there is an unknown object being used in this line

`document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = language[language_code]`

where the **language** object is never defined.

Other possible parts that could give an UnknownReference would be the lines containing `document.getElementById()` function call, if the html elements do not exist. You can check those as well.

Comment: The language object is a string defined earlier in the javascript file. The HTML elements are all called in de body.

Comment: okay it seems like a browser cache issue with your script can you do a cache refresh on chrome it should be `ctrl+shift+f5`